# Communication Issue with TCA9539 on MSP430FR4132

Tags: i2c, embedded, programming, msp430

I am trying to communicate with the TCA9539 using my MSP430FR4132, but I'm encountering issues setting the registers using I2C. I've connected pull-up resistors (10kΩ) to both the SCL and SDA lines. However, I'm unable to establish communication, and I'm unsure why.

I'm attaching my code below for your reference:

```
#include <msp430.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDR 0x74 // Address of the I2C slave device

void init_I2C(void);
void write_I2C_byte(unsigned char slave_addr, unsigned char reg_addr, unsigned char data);

void main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

    //For reset
    P2DIR |= 0x40;
    P2OUT |= 0x40;
    P2DIR &= ~0x80;
    // Initialize I2C
    init_I2C();
    __delay_cycles(300);
    write_I2C_byte(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x06, 0x00);
    write_I2C_byte(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x02, 0xff);
}

void init_I2C(void) {
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCSWRST;

  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3; //Choose I2C Mode
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMST;
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCSYNC;
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL_3;
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCSTEM;
  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR;
  UCB0BRW = 10;


  UCB0I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;

  P5SEL0 |= BIT2;
  P5SEL0 |= BIT3;

  UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;

}

void write_I2C_byte(unsigned char slave_addr, unsigned char reg_addr, unsigned char data) {
    while(UCB0STAT & UCBBUSY); // Wait until I2C bus is not busy

    UCB0I2CSA = slave_addr; // Set slave address
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT; // Set as transmitter and generate start condition

    while(!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0)); // Wait until TX buffer is ready
    UCB0TXBUF = reg_addr; // Send register address

    while(!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0)); // Wait until TX buffer is ready
    UCB0TXBUF = data; // Send data

    while(!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0)); // Wait until TX buffer is ready
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP; // Generate stop condition
}
```

Any insights into why I might be facing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Aswin Raj K - Have you looked at the I2C signals with an oscilloscope to evaluate (a) the signal quality and (b) to check whether the I2C activity matches what you expect from your code? If so, please [edit] the question to add that info & your analysis. || Doing that will help you avoid looking for problems in the code, if really the problem is with the hardware, for example. || FYI, as you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. TY

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Sam, I appreciate your message. I just wanted to let you know that I haven't had a chance to check the signals yet. However, from what I recall, it seems like the UCBBUSY status register is consistently high and the program is stuck in the first while loop.